# Polynomial factorization, how do I find a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a problem that requires me to do a factorization of:

$p(x) = 2x^{3}-3x^{2}-4x-1$

I have found out that I could solve it according to the factor theorem and polynomial division, I have so far come up with:

$p(a)=0 $
$\to p(x) = (x-a)*q(x)$

$q(x) = \frac{p(x)}{x-a}$

But I'm struggling on how to find $ a$ in $ x-a$ .
Can someone please explain this to me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This has a rational root.  use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: If finding $a$ was so easy then factor theorem would be obsolete. You have to guess $a$.

Comment: @lulu this was really hard to follow. does it mean that $p(x) = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$ gives a root of $\frac{d}{a}$, in this case $\frac{-1}{2}$? so $x-a$ is $x+ \frac{1}{2}$ or $2x+1$ ?

Comment: @Moo so my calculation was correct? I didn't fully get the rational root theorem and I'm afraid I simplified it a bit too much

Answer (score 0):

Well because it has degree 3, it has 3 factors. 2 of them are conjugates. As Moo said,

$$2x^{3}-3x^{2}-4x-1=(2 x+1)(x^2-2 x-1)$$ using the rational root theorem. Now we must factorise the quadratic. Have you done this in class yet? the roots are $p$ and $q$ such that $pq = c=-1$ and $p+q=b=2$ (alternatively, you can use the quadratic formula, but it's overkill here). Jumping to the end, the roots of the quadratic are: $$(1+\sqrt2,1-\sqrt2)$$